# Webform only sends email to the current user

Tags: webform-civicrm

On a test webform I have 2 contacts, 2 email addresses.

I populate the form with CIDs from the URL.

I'm wanting to send an email to contact 2. But it does not send.

It will only send an email to contact 1 - ie the current user.

The same even if I swap the CIDs around.

I'm using Webform CiviCRM v 7.x-4.26 and CiviCRM v 5.13.1.

It works OK in Webform CiviCRM v 7.x-4.26 and CiviCRM v 5.9.1

Is this a bug?

Comment: Hi Tony - can you please post what you have in the webform -> Emails tab?

Comment: Thanks Karin. I reverted to 5.9.1 so cannot replicate at the mo. I will when I do a new install somewhere.